# jquery ajax submit callback get this closet

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '#file-submit', function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function (data, status, jqxhr) {
        //here will be get a error
        var nextId = $(this).parents('.tab-pane').next().attr("id");
        alert(nextId);

    }).fail(function (data, status, jqxhr) {
        console.log("error");
    });
})
```

threr is a button in page, when the page submited,
i will get the value in the form element,
but the i cant get,
please give some point ,thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me at all what you're trying to describe.  The comment in the code indicates that there is an error.  What is the error?  What is this code trying to do, and at what point does it fail?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: `this` inside `done()` callback refers to something else than what you are thinking...

Comment: Thank you very much, I will pay attention to you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set relevant context to `done()` callback, e.g using `bind()` and btw, prefer to use `closest()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#file-submit', function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function (data, status, jqxhr) {
        //now 'this' refers to clicked element
        var nextId = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').next().attr("id");
        alert(nextId);

    }.bind(this)).fail(function (data, status, jqxhr) {
        console.log("error");
    });
})
```